# keep the first part and delete the rest on a specified line using sed

Tags: sed

I know a line number in a file, wherein I want to keep the first word and delete the rest till the end of the line. How do I do this using sed ?
So lets say, I want to go to line no 10 in a file, which looks like this -

goodword "blah blah"\

and what i want is
goodword

I have tried this -  sed 's/([a-z]*).*/\1/'
But this does it on all the lines in a file. I want it only on one specified line.

Comment: When you say "only on one specified line" do you mean only on line 10? If so, try `10s/([a-z]+).*/\\1/`

Comment: That did not work for me

Comment: Be sure to properly quote the string so the backslash occurs only once in the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "first word" you mean "everything up to the first space", and if by "retain this change in the file itself" you mean that you don't mind creating a new file with the same name as the previous file, and if you have a `sed` that supports `-i`, you can probably just do:

```
sed -i '10s/ .*//' input-file
```

If you want to be more restrictive in the definition of a word, you can use `'10s/\([a-z]*\).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use grep or awk to grab just one line, and then pipe it into sed (if grep or awk couldn't do the entire job for you) to work on just one line? I think the key here is isolating that one line first, and then worrying about extracting something from it.

Comment: I want to retain this change in the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==10 {print $1}' file
goodword
```